# Социальная активность

Tags: лексика

Здравствуйте. Есть ли какой-то термин для обозначения социальной активности как черты человека? Ну, например, когда он ходит в разные кружки, общается с людьми, принимает участие в общественной жизни и т.л.?

Answer (score 3):

Такого термина нет. В психологии так и пишут - социальная, или общественная активность.
 Если всё-таки искать именно ту черту личности, которая способствует этой социальной активности, то наиболее близким термином будет экстравертность.

Интроверсия  и экстраверсия — это характеристики типичных отличий между людьми, крайние точки которых отвечают преобладающей ориентированности человека или на внешний мир (экстраверты), или на свой собственный мир (интроверты). У всех людей имеются признаки интровертированного и экстравертированного типа. Разница между людьми заключается в соотношении данных признаков. Разграничение людей на данные типы происходит с учётом таких качеств, как общительность, разговорчивость, тщеславие, настойчивость, энергичность и другие. Интроверты робкие, скромные, имеют склонность к уединению. Они уравновешенны, мало с кем сближаются, из-за этого имеют мало друзей, но очень преданны им. Экстраверты, вежливы, открыты, приветливы, коммуникабельны, изобретательны в общении, тщеславны, напористы, активны, у них много друзей, имеют склонность к устному общению.

Хотя конечно же понятно, что при определённых обстоятельствах описанную вами активную социальную жизнь может вести и типичный интроверт, но его подобная вовлечённость в социум будет тяготить.

Answer (score 1):

На ум приходят только коммуникабельность, общительность, отзывчивость. Не уверена, что это подойдет...